Looking for citation of a definition of multivariable integral
I need a definition of Multivariable Riemann Integral to cite in my article.

I've been searching different cited sources, for example Rudin, Folland, Stewart and Larson books.
In the first two I found only one variable definition, in the last two I saw definitions for $3$ variables at maximum.
I need something like  this.

Can you please tell me a good source to cite in a research article ?
P.S. For some reason I cannot reply directly, I apologize for this. I'm writing an interdisciplinary article which is not intended for a math journal but for another field. The main discipline does not use integrals at this point at all. My readers could learn calculus in the past and they use derivatives, but integrals could be carelessly forgotten.
Thanks a lot to everybody! I will try Wikipedia link first, and see if I can get away with it. For some reason, I cannot upvote answers I found useful. I guess I do not have enough good karma on this forum.

I have to ask: are you sure you need a citation? For a math, physics, or engineering research paper, I really wouldn't think you'd need a citation... the precise basic facts about multi-variable integrals are 170+ years old, and mathematicians were using them (accurately) for a couple centuries before that... Can you clarify, regarding the general topic of your paper?

Why not cite the Wikipedia article? Why is a citation needed? Are you expecting people reading your article to not know what a multivariable Riemann integral to be?

You definitely do not need a citation, unless it is a paper on the history of Math, or maybe on Math Education...

Spivak Calculus on Manifolds, or Munkres Analysis on Manifolds, or Duistermaat Kolk’s book, or Loomis and Sternberg, or Hubbard & Hubbard etc

Thanks for clarifying. I think the Wikipedia article is best. If the readers do not know or remember calculus well, I don’t see much point in pointing them to an advanced math textbook.
